# How to properly handle AM/PM times in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, time

I have an API that saves start times and end times to the database. The times are saved in UTC.

For example if my `start_time` is 9:00 AM EST, it will be saved in my database as 14:00:00. Similarly, when my `end_time` is 10:00 PM EST, it will be saved in my database as 03:00:00.

Both of these are Time fields in Postgres.

When I go to retrieve these times in a separate API, the `start_time` is parsed fine, but the `end_time` is parsed as if it is 3 PM. Doing `end_time.hour` gives me 15. I want this to be 3 AM so when I convert it back to Eastern Standard Time, I can get 10:00 PM.

How can I do this?

Edit:

1. I am using the `time` type in Postgres.
2. Timezone on my server is in UTC.
3. The API is an endpoint on a separate controller that passes these values to my client.
4. The server (that also serves the API) is being run locally in the `America/Toronto` timezone and in the `America/New York` timezone for production (which is the same timezone).

Comment: This is going to need a lot more information: 1) The exact Postgres type `time` or `timetz`? 2) The result of `show timezone;` on your server 3) What is the API software? 4) Where is the API being run and it's time zone?

Comment: I've put the information requested in the edit.

Comment: I would suggest checking the output of the API before the database insert to check for corruption at that point. Can you get access to the variables at that point?

Comment: **Caution:** Perhaps not directly related but you shouldn't  use 'EST'. That is a timezone abbreviation. The problem being timezone abbreviations do not adjust for for daylight savings time. They are always fixed offsets. Better to use full timezone names as they do adjust for daylight savings time. Use either the timezones mentioned  or simply "US/Eastern".

Comment: In the application, I use ''America/Toronto" etc. Was just referring to it as EST for it to be more clear.

Comment: I am not seeing how `03:00:00` can be transformed into `15:00:00` in either 12 or 24 time? What code are you using to parse the time?